# Can you use "stub out" as a verb regarding code development?

Tags: verbs

I know that in code development people talk about "stubs," which are bits of dummy code. In plumbing, "stub-outs" are blind ends of plumbing waiting for fixtures to be installed later.

Can you verb that noun? Can you say "stub that out," "stub out those [things]," or "stub that"?

Comment: Whether you should or shouldn't, you certainly can, and many people do.

Comment: I'm sure the normal software-specific sense of ***stub*** doesn't directly derive from anything to do with plumbing. It just means a "dummy" function that's been created specifically so it can be *called* by other parts of a program, but which doesn't *yet* contain any functional code. My guess is that anyone using ***stub out*** is simply deriving it from ***comment out*** (prevent previously functional code from being executed, by converting it to *comments*). But it seems a bit "ass-about-face" to apply that term to a function that doesn't even contain any "real" code anyway.

Comment: (To put it more bluntly, the usage of "stub out", as a verb in the software biz, is quite common.)

Comment: I've never worried about where the software sense of the term came from.  It's plausible to me that it comes from the plumbing term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: references to stub-outs in plumbing are much older than in programming, and the function in plumbing is the exact same. But yes, perhaps they share the common, older ancestor of "stub."

Comment: It is interesting to contrast this usage with stubbing out a cigarette.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm a software developer and I have often heard and used "stub" or "stub out" as verbs meaning "to write temporary placeholders for more complicated code to be put in place later."

An example:  "I started by stubbing out the interface."

Comment: Completely anecdotal then, without references to work of authority on the subject matter.